# Im trying to use webbrowser control to login automatic to a website forum but it never log in what could be wrong?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, winforms

This is the link for the login:

[Log In](http://www.tapuz.co.il/Common/SignInPage.aspx?backUrl=http://www.tapuz.co.il/Common/SignIn.aspx@loginDone=1)

If im trying to login manualy in the webbrowser it does nothing but open a popup message ask me if to close the window i click yes and nothing happen. In the regular chrome browser not in the webbrowser when i put in user name and password and click log in it also close the window of the log in automatic refresh the page and im logged in. 
But through the webbroswer its never log in. Its not givinig any errors or exceptions just does nothing.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Permissions;

namespace Champinos
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        WebClient webc = new WebClient();
        string url = "";
        string username = "";
        string password = "";
        string commit = ""; //this matches the data from Tamper Data

        private int timeElapsed;
        private string newline1 = "";
        private bool complete;
        private int count;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            timeElapsed = 1;
            label3.Visible = false;
            label5.Visible = false;
            complete = false;
            count = 1;
        }

        void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            url = "http://www.tapuz.co.il/Common/SignInPage.aspx?backUrl=http://www.tapuz.co.il/Common/SignIn.aspx@loginDone=1";
            username = "yasonikolados";
            password = "ynnad1972";
            commit = "Login";//"Sign+In";

            label1.Text = "Completed";

            string source = "";
            source = webc.DownloadString("http://www.tapuz.co.il/forums2008/forumpage.aspx?forumid=393&r=1");

            string start = "data-token=";
            string end = " href";
            int firstTag = source.IndexOf(start);
            int lastTag = source.IndexOf(end, firstTag);
            int startIndex = firstTag + start.Length + 1;
            int endIndex = lastTag;
            string authenticityToken = source.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex - 30);
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted2;
            string postData = string.Format(
                "authenticity_token={2}&session" + 
                "[username_or_email]={0}&session[password]={1}&commit={3}",
                  username, password, authenticityToken, commit);
            ASCIIEncoding enc = new ASCIIEncoding();
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.tapuz.co.il/Common/SignInPage.aspx?backUrl=http://www.tapuz.co.il/Common/SignIn.aspx@loginDone", "", enc.GetBytes(postData), "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.tapuz.co.il/forums2008/forumpage.aspx?forumid=393&r=1");

        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted2(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowser b = sender as WebBrowser;
            string response = b.DocumentText;

            if (response.Contains("Sign out"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login Successful");
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: qamar post i think. In the completed event im using postdata to post my loag in and password destaid so it will log in automatic.

Comment: Getting a page with a WebClient won't help you to get the valid token. It should be the token that appears in the page in your WebBrowser control.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using `webBrowser1.Navigate` as the last call in your `DocumentCompleted` event handler. Since you added the `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted2` as the event handler for the `DocumentCompleted` event prior to the `Navigate` call, what is happening is that when the call to Navigate happens, it is immediately calling your `DocumentCompleted2` function which is signing you out. Instant signin and signout.

If you want to confirm, place breakpoints at the first line of both the `DocumentCompleted` and `DocumentCompleted2` functions and debug it.

Comment: Sujay i tried to remove the completed2 event marked it with // not use the register to the event and the handler so only completed event is in use and same reslut it didnt log me in. What it does is bring me back to the log in page. First its loading the site then for milisecond its going to another page and jump to the login . And thats it its not logging in just leave me in the login page.

Comment: Looks like you are either missing a parameter that the login form's processor is expecting or some values are incorrect. How did you decode this login procedure? The website does not work for me, so unable to follow through with your code.